# ADF dataflow creates blobs with 0 commited blocks in ADLS gen 2

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm creating files in ADLS Gen 2 account using ADF dataflow. The blob type is shown as "Block blob" in the storage UI. The file content looks good. However, while trying to read the blob programmatically, I get the committed blocks as 0. This issue is happening after upgrading the blob storage to ADLS Gen 2. Not sure if this is ADF issue or ADLS gen 2 issue.

Sample code

```
string connectionString = "";
string containerName = "test";
string blobName = "test.json";

BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

BlockBlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName);

var committedBlocks = await blobClient.GetBlockListAsync(BlockListTypes.All);

foreach (var block in committedBlocks.Value.CommittedBlocks)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Block Name: {block.Name}");
}
```

Comment: can you share your sample code?

Comment: Added the sample test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple things, only SAS auth from ADF to Gen 2 allows creation of  blobs with committed blocks. This works only if you use storage blob linked service, not ADLS Gen 2 linked service. This looks like a bug or design flaw on ADF. This information should be publicly documented so that customers are aware that ADF-ADLS Gen2 integration is inefficient to process large blobs.

Answer (score 0):

To read the content of a block blob in ADLS Gen2, you may not need to list committed blocks as you would with Azure Blob Storage. You can simply download the blob's content directly, like this:

```cs
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

string connectionString = "<connectionString>";
string containerName = "<containerName>";
string blobName = "<blobName>";

BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

BlobDownloadInfo blobDownloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(blobDownloadInfo.Content))
{
    string content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Blob Content:");
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

It will read the blob content as shown below:

[image]

- Confirm that the ADF dataflow or activity responsible for creating the blob in ADLS Gen2 is correctly configured and completes without errors. It may be one of the reasons for getting zero blocks.

Comment: The issue is not reading the content of the blob, but writing/reading the blobs as committed blocks in Gen2. The blob creation completes without errors and has all the data.

Comment: You can [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs) regarding block blobs.